# Element disappears as soon as I make its position absolute

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place `.blob` at a particular position inside a container behind an image.

The blob shows up in the container quite fine but as soon as I make it `position: absolute`, the blob disappears. The container position is relative and the image position is absolute:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px),
screen and (max-height: 900px) {
  .landing {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #F8D0B0;
  }
  .landing img {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 13%;
    right: 6.5%;
  }
  .blob {
    Position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    max-width: 90%;
    height: 40.5%;
    background-color: #88D8B8;
    border-radius: 40% 60% 60% 40% / 40% 40% 60% 60%;
    z-index: -2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="landing">
  <img src="people.png" alt="">
  <div class="blob">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give your blob a fixed `width` and set a higher `z-index`

Answer (score 1):

As Lee Taylor mentioned in their comment, use a fixed width and higher z-index.

- Your div had a width of auto, and because it had no content that meant zero width - max width will not get it to be that width, think of max-width more like a cap on how wide it can get.
- lower z-index values send an element back into the screen and higher values pull it closer toward you

I try and keep my CSS at as few lines as possible so it's easier to diagnose problems like this.

You rarely have to explicitly define `height: auto` for example. And declaring `width: 100%` on a block-level element such as a `div` does nothing because it's already set to `auto` when you do nothing, and that takes up the full width by default.

With your media queries, aim to use `min-width` and `min-height` instead, and **add** in layout complexity on larger screens, rather than having bespoke small screen width styles

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px),
screen and (max-height: 900px) {
  .landing {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #F8D0B0;
  }
  .landing img {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 90%;
    bottom: 13%;
    right: 6.5%;
  }
  .blob {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 40.5%;
    background-color: #88D8B8;
    border-radius: 40% 60% 60% 40% / 40% 40% 60% 60%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="landing">
  <img src="http://source.unsplash.com/random/100x100" alt="">
  <div class="blob">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you set the position of the element to absolute, the "max-width" property no longer works properly. Instead of using `max-width:90%` in the css, you should just use `width:90%". Also, setting the element's position to absolute makes the z-index css property affect the element. Since the z-index of the blob is -2 while the z-index of the element with class landing is 0 by default, the element will not render in the body. Try the code below:

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px),
screen and (max-height: 900px) {
  .landing {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #F8D0B0;
  }
  .landing img {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 13%;
    right: 6.5%;
  }
  .blob {
    Position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    max-width: 90%;
    height: 40.5%;
    background-color: #88D8B8;
    border-radius: 40% 60% 60% 40% / 40% 40% 60% 60%;
    z-index: -2;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="landing">
  <img src="http://source.unsplash.com/random/100x100" alt="">
  <div class="blob">
  </div>
</div>
```